# save output to file instead of screen for nested script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script which calls several functions. These functions contain print commands (to the screen). How can I save the output of the script to a file without printing it to the screen and without changing the code of the functions.

Best,
Wouter

Comment: Use shell redirection `scriptname > filename`

Comment: That's not working. It thought that was because the shell script calls other scripts and those other scripts execute the print commands.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, they all inherit the output redirection.

Comment: As long as they're not writing directly to the terminal with `>/dev/tty`.

Comment: Post the print commands in the functions.

Comment: In fact, a perl script calls a shell script and this executes a Java function in which the print statement is, for example

Comment: outstream.println("Set INTERLEAVED to "+FASTQ.FORCE_INTERLEAVED);

Comment: Try to add `2>&1` . i.e. `scriptname > filename 2>&1` just to be sure that you redirect to file both stdin and stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `script` command which stores on a file everything written to the screen:

```
script -c "myscript arguments ..." /tmp/myscript.log
```

That will at least allow you to get what was output to `/dev/tty` by the called functions, however, there is no simple way to prevent this output to go on your screen too.